# Format terrible string with Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I need to format this string with Javascript:

```
data:"{extra_text_pared=FELICIDADESSS GUILLE, idioma=ES, nombre=Antonio, de_parte_de=TU FAMILIA}"
```

I need this output:

```
    extra_text_pared=FELICIDADESSS GUILLE
    idioma=ES
    nombre=Antonio
    de_parte_de=TU FAMILIA
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking for whether a string manipulation solution or parsing it as an object ?

Comment: Try: `obj.data.slice(1, -1).split(", ").join("\n")`

Comment: The [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) should help you to do what you want. If not, you can use [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Can you fix the source to return a common data structure? If you can, you most definitely should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method on string.

Like

```js
var str = "{extra_text_pared=FELICIDADESSS GUILLE, idioma=ES, nombre=Antonio, de_parte_de=TU FAMILIA}";
var formatedStr = str.replace(/,/g, '\n').replace(/{|}/g, '')

console.log(formatedStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use split

```js
var obj={data:"{extra_text_pared=FELICIDADESSS GUILLE, idioma=ES, nombre=Antonio, de_parte_de=TU FAMILIA}"}
obj.data.slice(1,-1).split(',').forEach(function(e){console.log(e)})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string:

```
let str = "{extra_text_pared=FELICIDADESSS GUILLE, idioma=ES, nombre=Antonio, de_parte_de=TU FAMILIA}";
let splitted = str.replace(/{|}| /g, '').split(',');
splitted.forEach(f=> console.log(f));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var text ="{extra_text_pared=FELICIDADESSS GUILLE, idioma=ES, nombre=Antonio, de_parte_de=TU FAMILIA}";
var obj =text.slice(1, -1).split(", ");



var newObj = {};

obj.forEach(function(element) {

  let oneObj =element.split("=");
  newObj[oneObj[0]] =oneObj[1];
});

console.log(newObj);
```